# Bison: using the Union semantic type with a C++ parser

Tags: c++, bison

I've been trying to set up a little parser in Bison, but when I try to build it I get:

> stone.tab.cc: In member function ‘virtual int yy::StoneParser::parse()’:
>   stone.tab.cc:507:81: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘StoneDriver&’ from an rvalue of type ‘yy::StoneParser::semantic_type*’
>         yyla.type = yytranslate_ (yylex (&yyla.value, &yyla.location, driver));

I suspect the reason is there's a problem using union-defined semantic types with a bison-generated C++ compiler, but I can't seem to resolve it...

How can I generate a valid C++ bison parser with 'union' semantic definitions?

stone.yy:

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require "3.0.4"

%defines
%define parser_class_name {StoneParser}

%code requires
{
# include <string>
class StoneDriver;
}

%param { StoneDriver& driver }

%locations

%code
{
# include "StoneDriver.hpp"
}

%union
{
   int intVal;
   char* stringVal;
}

%token <stringVal> KEY_ENUM
%token <stringVal> KEY_CLASS

%token K_TEST
%token T_ID

%type <stringVal> class
%type <stringVal> enum

%%

input: toplevel_declarations

toplevel_declarations: toplevel_declarations toplevel_declaration
    | %empty

toplevel_declaration: class
    | enum

class: KEY_CLASS { $$ = "test"; }

enum: KEY_ENUM { $$ = "test"; }
```

StoneDriver.hpp

```
#ifndef STONEDRIVER_INCLUDED_HPP
#define STONEDRIVER_INCLUDED_HPP
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "stone.tab.hh"

class StoneDriver;

//Tell Flex the lexer's prototype ...
#define YY_DECL \
  yy::StoneParser::symbol_type yylex (StoneDriver& driver)
// ... and declare it for the parser's sake.
YY_DECL;

//Scans and parses Stone
class StoneDriver
{
   public:
      //Constructor
      StoneDriver();

      //Destructor
      virtual ~StoneDriver();

  std::map<std::string, int> variables;

  int result;
  // Handling the scanner.
  void scan_begin ();
  void scan_end ();
  bool trace_scanning;
  // Run the parser on file F.
  // Return 0 on success.
  int parse (const std::string& f);
  // The name of the file being parsed.
  // Used later to pass the file name to the location tracker.
  std::string file;
  // Whether parser traces should be generated.
  bool trace_parsing;
  // Error handling.
  void error (const yy::location& l, const std::string& m);
  void error (const std::string& m);
};//StoneDriver

#endif
```

StoneDriver.cpp:

```
#include "StoneDriver.hpp"
#include "stone.tab.hh"

StoneDriver::StoneDriver()
  : trace_scanning (false), trace_parsing (false)
{
   variables["one"] = 1;
   variables["two"] = 2;
}//constructor

StoneDriver::~StoneDriver()
{
}//destructor

int StoneDriver::parse(const std::string &f)
{
   file = f;
   scan_begin();
   yy::StoneParser parser(*this);

   #if YYDEBUG
      parser.set_debug_level(trace_parsing);
   #endif

   int res = parser.parse();
   scan_end();

   return res;
}//parse

void StoneDriver::error(const yy::location& l, const std::string& m)
{
  std::cerr << l << ": " << m << std::endl;
}//error

void StoneDriver::error(const std::string& m)
{
  std::cerr << m << std::endl;
}//error
```

SOLUTION:
Rici showed that the method signature for YY_DECL should be defined like so:

```
int yylex (semantic_type* YYLVAL, location_type* YYLLOC, TYPE1 ARG1, ...)
```

In my case, the magic line was:

```
#define YY_DECL int yylex( yy::StoneParser::semantic_type* const lval, yy::StoneParser::location_type* location, StoneDriver& driver )
```

- `yy::` is the namespace from my Bison file (stone.yy in my case)
- `StoneParser` is the defined parser_class_name from stone.yy
- `location_type` is required because stone.yy has %locations
  defined.
- `StoneDriver&` is the parsing context from stone.yy,
  defined as `%param { StoneDriver& driver }`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message provides a somewhat clear indication of what the problem is, although it is oddly focused on the type mismatch in the first argument to `yylex` rather than the fact that the prototype you provide for `yylex` has only one parameter whereas the call has three arguments. Clang is clearer:

```
stone.tab.cc:474:39: error: no matching function for call to 'yylex'
            yyla.type = yytranslate_ (yylex (&yyla.value, &yyla.location, driver));
                                      ^~~~~
./stone_driver.hpp:14:1: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'driver', but 3 arguments were provided
YY_DECL;
^
```

The bison info file, section 10.1.5.1, describes the calling convention of `yylex` from C++ scanners with a `union` semantic type:

```
The interface is as follows.

 -- Method on parser: int yylex (semantic_type* YYLVAL, location_type*
          YYLLOC, TYPE1 ARG1, ...)
 -- Method on parser: int yylex (semantic_type* YYLVAL, TYPE1 ARG1, ...)
     Return the next token.  Its type is the return value, its semantic
     value and location (if enabled) being YYLVAL and YYLLOC.
     Invocations of ‘%lex-param {TYPE1 ARG1}’ yield additional
     arguments.
```

This is effectively the same calling convention as is used with pure parsers in the C API: the first two arguments to `yylex` (if locations are enabled, as is the case in your program) are the address of the semantic value object and the address of the location object; the third and subsequent arguments are the parameters specified by `%param` (if present).

So you should fix the definition of `YY_DECL` according to the above prototype.

You will also have to change your flex actions to treat `yylval` (or whatever you call the first parameter) as a pointer rather than a union, which mostly means changing `.` to `->`.