# Bison trying to use free yylex() function on C++ parser

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I am using Flex+Bison to generate a C++ scanner/parser but hitting issues where flex functions are missing from generated code and included headers.

The compilation with g++ fails with the following:

```
parser.cxx: In member function 'virtual int yy::parser::parse()':
parser.cxx:465:38: error: 'yylex' was not declared in this scope
             symbol_type yylookahead (yylex (yylval, yylloc));
```

It is an error since it should not use the global free function `yylex(...)` but rather my scanner's `yy::scanner::yylex(...)` function, implemented as follows:

```
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#include "parser.hxx"

#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL yy::parser::symbol_type yy::scanner::yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type* yylval, yy::parser::location_type* yylloc)

namespace yy {

class scanner final: public yyFlexLexer
{
  public:
    scanner(std::istream *in, std::ostream* out): yyFlexLexer(in, out) {}

    parser::symbol_type yylex(yy::parser::semantic_type* yylval, yy::parser::location_type* yylloc);
};
```

Those parameters are configured in .y file as:

```
%param {parser::semantic_type* yylval} {parser::location_type* yylloc}
```

Both flex (.l) and bison (.y) files are being compiled with flags to generate C++ code and compiled with g++ as:

```
g++ -lfl parser.cxx scanner.cxx -o lang
```

As `parser.cxx` and `scanner.cxx` are the generated files. What am I missing, how can I fix what function the parser should be calling instead of `yylex()`?

Comment: This macro is used by flex to implement the function body with the correct signature later on [(source)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Calc_002b_002b-Parsing-Driver.html)

Comment: So none of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27yylex%27+was+not+declared+in+this+scope&oq=%27yylex%27+was+not+declared+in+this+scope&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.467j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) helped?

Comment: Nope. I visited the first ~40 results of googling for no luck.

Comment: What is the mechanism you use to communicate to bison the name of the scanner function?

Comment: @rici besides using the default name of `yy::scanner`, I could not find anything else to do it

Comment: @ranisalt: I think the usual technique involves adding `#define yylex ... ` to your bison prolog, where `...` is the name of the lexer function (which will normally be a member function of some scanner object, no?) I don't use the C++ APIs much, since I prefer the simple API provided by the C skeletons.

Comment: Your question answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218920/bison-using-the-union-semantic-type-with-a-c-parser

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows

```
#undef yylex
#define yylex scanner.yylex  // bison's parse() invokes scanner.yylex(),
```